# Inclusion of correlation structure glmer function of package lme4

Tags: r, data-structures, correlation, lme4

I am using the glmer function of the lme4 package of R. My answer is Bernoulli and my data are longitudinal.

In the bild Package, I have already found article using Mc1 or MC2 for correlation structures.

Is there any way I can use the glmer function and be able to include a correlation structure? If it is not possible, could you tell me which default is?

The code in R is only to facilitate the help.

```
library(dplyr)
n = 300
xx<-c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5")
xxx<-c("e1","e2","e3")
p=0.3
df1 <- data_frame(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
 School = factor(sample(xxx, n,re=TRUE)),
 yx = as.factor(rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = p))
)
df1
library(lme4)
mm2 <- glmer(yx ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 +  (1 | School), data = df1, 
family = "binomial",control = glmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE))
```